# Error 32512 (driver return code)

Tags: xetex, errors, pdftex, texlive, ubuntu

I'm using XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998

I'm creating .tex file using PHP and storing it on linux server. [ex: abc.tex]
Then creating .sh file with command to execute *.tex file using XeLaTeX [ex: abc.sh]

sample content of abc.sh

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex abc.tex
```

If i execute abc.sh on linux command prompt, required PDF is getting generated.
But, If i execute abc.sh from apache webserver via php, it's giving error as :

```
Error 32512 (driver return code) generating output;
file abc.pdf may not be valid.
```

**Note: There is NO PDF File generated**.

Can you please suggest any pointers to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally it got executed. **DANGER** part is that, still I don't know reason. 
I suspect it may be due to some path issue.

Instead of executing tex file using xelatex, i complied it with latex & then with dvips and finally converted PDF using ps2pdf

NOTE: it's getting executed via webserver using PHP

Comment: Can you show the `exec(...)` arguments for whole line of compilation? I have absolutely the same problem!

Comment: Hi Ruben, Basically I call shell script from exec('/bin/sh  abc.sh'); and commands are written in this .sh file ; shell file will have latex , dvips & ps2pdf for compilation in sequence.

Comment: I did it by this two lines: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141221/27881

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working way to execute latex from PHP. The point is that functions as `exec`, `shell_exec`, `passthru`, etc. get no or a vary limited `PATH` variable. However, `latex`, `pdflatex` and others use the path variable to call other programs. We therefore need to set the path appropriately, for example as follows:

```php
passthru('PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH pdflatex file.tex');
```

Also note that your webserver user (typically `www-data` or `apache`) should have the necessary packages installed; this may not be the case if you're using local tlmgr stores.