# Why php exec() fails .tex→xelatex→.pdf, but succeed .tex→xelatex→.xdv→xdvipdfmx→.pdf?

Tags: xetex, compiling, xdvipdfmx

The call of command:

```
$dir = "/path/to/source/file";
exec("cd $dir;xelatex filesource.tex", $output_array[0]);
```

always fails, but:

```
$dir = "/path/to/source/file";
exec("cd $dir;/usr/texbin/xelatex -no-pdf filesource.tex", $output_array[0]);// now we have .xdv file
exec("cd $dir;/usr/texbin/xdvipdfmx filesource.xdv", $output_array[1]);
```

succeed, and result .pdf file absolutely valid. What is the trick?

Comment: Getting any errors?

Comment: XeTeX spawns an `xdvipdfmx` process and pipes shipped out pages to it, unless `--no-pdf` is specified. It's possible that this fools `exec`.

Comment: I suspect xelatex without -no-pdf makes some kind .xdv but lost the path before final compilation. If it is, I want to find the way to fix this failure and understand the whole picture.

Comment: did you try adding the `-output-directory=` option to xelatex?

Comment: Oh yes! I did it in my first 50 attempts. Xelatex starts produce files to the `-output-directory`, but eventually loses the path and can not find his own .aux file, just a moment ago made by himself.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to "configure" the environment in one session scope?

Comment: Are there any news here? Have you been able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Johannes_B: No news, sorry! Probably the problem in the PATH variables in the system, but I did not dug deeper.

Comment: The question itself seems to be quite interesting, you could make an edit to the question, maybe add a little detail. That way it goes up to the top on main site, or in other words, it gets bumped ;-)

Comment: What works for me is using chdir from PHP to change into the .tex directory. Then executing the commands and then changing directory back. Does that help?

Comment: Pretty sure the issue here is with the path to the command: in the first case you're just calling the executable `xelatex` (which I'd be very surprised if PHP could find by default), while in the latter case you're calling all executables with their full path: `/usr/texbin/xelatex` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In general there are two main cases:

- your LaTeX binaries are known to the system (whichever you might use): This case is pretty simple because you can simply use your first approach without a full path to the binaries.
- your LaTeX binaries are unknown to the system: If you install LaTeX not over repositories (if you're on Linux), but with the TeX Live installer f.i. you'll find them in a location that's unknown to the system. You have to add them to the PATH so that it can be found. The alternative is to use full paths when calling.

You seem to have a system of the second type. So you should either tell PHP to add the LaTeX binary path to PATH or should use full paths when calling.