# Why does Error 256 (driver return code) yield an exit status of 0 (return code 0)?

Tags: errors, xetex, linux, unix

I may have discovered a problem with `xelatex`. Unfortunately, I do not know how to reproduce Error 256 easily. What I know is that it occurs when running an automated script that iterates over many TeX files, and not when I process a specific file. The dubious nature of this problem makes it difficult for me to identify conditions which cause the problem. Actually, I am not interested in solving the problem here anyway. What strikes me as odd is that my script is designed to detect error codes (if return code is not 0, then identify that junk and tell me).

The process call is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error DVDCover.tex
```

which should return and yield a non-zero at any sign of trouble--this would be the expected behavior of normal Unix binaries.

So more frightening than the problem itself is that `xelatex` returns with 0 as if all were good. The last couple lines in the log read as follows:

```
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file DVDCover.pdf may not be valid.
```

## Notes

- Related question: [Error 256 (driver return code): No pdf produced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287233/error-256-driver-return-code-no-pdf-produced)
- Ticket opened at sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/140/

Comment: The error code is probably a font problem. Can't you remove the pdf before calling xelatex and then check in your script if a new one has be created? That's how my editor checks if xelatex has run successfully.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the tip. The script pulls a fresh revision from a version control system (PDFs are not part of the VCS), therefore I can exclude the problem of existing PDFs. All other PDFs are successfully created using a common preamble. Anyway, the most reliable way to verify the success of a subprocess *should* be to check the exit code (it gets passed to the parent process when `exit` is called). If a process has an error, it should exit non-zero. That's how Unix rolls.

Comment: You get error code 1 (from xdvipdfmx) if you call first `xelatex --no-pdf ...`  and then `xdvipdfmx file.xdv`. And xetex *does* check the exit code of `xdvipdfmx`, after all it adds a message to the log and the terminal. But it looks as if it doesn't change its own status if the  driver exists with 1. You could ask on the xetex or texlive list if there is a way to change this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is scary behavior, but I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this from the unanswered list.

When `xdvipdfmx` fails one gets error code 1 (from xdvipdfmx) if one calls first `xelatex --no-pdf` and then `xdvipdfmx file.xdv`.

In the "combined" compilation `xelatex file` `xetex` obviously does check the exit code of `xdvipdfmx`, after all it adds a message to the log and the terminal. But currently  it doesn't change its own status if the driver exists with 1.

This has been discussed on the xetex site: https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/140/. This bug has been resolved future versions will exit with status 1 when the driver fails.